# Add extra wysiwyg block to cms page form

Tags: magento2, cms, wysiwyg

I've been trying to work out how to add a new wysiwyg block on my cms page form as I need 2 different blocks on each page.

I've been looking into the Cms module and I guess I need to extend view/adminhtml/ui_component/cms_block_form.xml in some way, but I'm not sure how, can someone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: I do not understand what are you trying to do.  Wysiwyg is an abbreviate of type of editor. What in this context would be a Wysiwyg block? All content of cms pages is managed inside of this editor window and you can add inside any amount of cms block you might wish to. I do not follow really.

Comment: Sorry for not being more clear, I want to add an exact copy of the content block in the backend cms form, but obviously with a different name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add a custom attributes to cms page See this tutorial:

https://www.magevision.com/blog/post/add-custom-field-to-cms-page-magento-2/

Answer (score 1):

You will need to extend the cms_page_form.xml

like

```
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="content">
        <field name="custom_content">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string"/>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">wysiwyg</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">page</item>
                    <item name="wysiwyg" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">custom_content</item>
                    <item name="additionalClasses" xsi:type="string">admin__field-wide</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

This [post](https://www.magevision.com/blog/post/add-custom-field-to-cms-page-magento-2/) will help you to achieve that.